# guidelines for importing modules in python

Tags: python, python-import

I know that there have been a number of questions concerning importing modules in python, but my question seems to be somewhat different.

I'm trying to understand when you have to import a whole module as opposed to when you have to import a specific entry in the module. It seems that only one of the two ways work.

For example if I want to use basename, importing os.path doesn't do the trick.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> basename('scripts/cy.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'basename' is not defined
```

Instead I need to import basename from os.path as in

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> basename('scripts/cy.py')
'cy.py'
```

Going the other way, if I want to use shutil.copyfile, importing copyfile from shutil doesn't work

```
>>> 
>>> from shutil import copyfile
>>> 
>>> shutil.copyfile('emma','newemma')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'shutil' is not defined
```

Instead I must import shutil as in

```
>>> 
>>> import shutil
>>> 
>>> shutil.copyfile('emma','newemma')
'newemma'
>>>
```

The only way I have been able to get this right is through experimentation.
Are there some guidelines to avoid experimentation?

Comment: What it comes down to is: You can only reference whatever strings you've used in the `import` statement, thus `import a.b; a.b.c()` is valid and so is `from a.b import c; c()`, but these two are invalid: `import a.b; c()` (You're treating it like a global object), `from a.b import c; c()` (The module is 'forgotten' by Python).

Comment: I guess you're used to the way `#include` works in C. In Python, you're not copy-pasting the module. The interpreter opens it, reads it and interprets it, then creates a 'variable' pointing at the module and its contents.

Comment: And great, I can't edit my comment anymore, but the last sample should be `from a.b import c; a.b.c()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you import

```
import os.path
```

then you have to use full namespace `os.path`

```
os.path.basename()
```

If you import with `from`

```
from shutil import copyfile
```

then you don't have to use full namespace `shutil`

```
copyfile(...)
```

That's all.

---

If you use `as`

```
import os.path as xxx
```

then you have to use `xxx` instead of `os.path`

```
xxx.basename()
```

---

If you use `from` and `as`

```
from os.path import basename as xxx
```

then you have to use `xxx` instead of `basename`

```
xxx()
```

Comment: `xxx.basename()`

Answer (score -1):

you could use form module import *

```
from time import *
sleep(2)
```

which allow you to call its submodules, instead of:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
```

or:

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

this imports every sub-module of the package
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: Don't do this.  `from ... import *` makes a mess of your namespace and is bad style.

Comment: this is exactly what he asked for, and even tho I shared a link to the documentation when it points out all it's side effects and if the module designer made an __all__ it won't make a mess, so why this down-vote? :T @jwodder